# hide the custom button in the uitableviewcell when long pressed in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i have put one custom button inside in the table cell.here i want to hide that button when long press the cell and shows when the cancel button is clicked.

this Before Editing:

[image]

the arrow button is custom button, this want to be hide when long presssed,show when cancel is clicked
[image]

here the table delegate functions:

```
    -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [name count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
NSLog(@"select press");

  static NSString *identifier=@"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cellVal=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
if (cellVal == nil) {
    cellVal = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
}
cellVal.layer.cornerRadius = 9;
titleLabel=(UILabel *)[cellVal viewWithTag:3];
locationLabel=(UILabel *)[cellVal viewWithTag:4];
timeLabel=(UILabel *)[cellVal viewWithTag:5];
detailButton=(UIButton *)[cellVal viewWithTag:10];
detailButton.tag=indexPath.row;

if(!btn){
     detailButton.hidden=NO;
}
else{detailButton.hidden=YES;
}

titleLabel.text=[name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
locationLabel.text=[loc objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
timeLabel.text=[time objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if (userSelectedAll == TRUE) {
    [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
} else if (userSelectedAll == FALSE) {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
}    
return cellVal;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     NSLog(@"didSelectRowAtIndexPath %ld",(long)indexPath.row);
            [arSelectedRows addObject:indexPath];

}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     NSLog(@"did De SelectRowAtIndexPath");
            [arSelectedRows removeObject:indexPath];
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle==UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        [[DataBaseFile getSharedInstance]delete:[[DataBaseFile getSharedInstance] getDBFilePath] withName:[[reminderList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] integerValue]];
    }
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Below is the long press code:

```
    -(void)handleLongPress1:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    self.cancelOut.hidden=NO;
    self.selectAllOut.hidden=NO;
    btn=TRUE;
    self.tableVW.allowsSelection=NO;
    self.tableVW.allowsMultipleSelection=YES;
    self.toolBarOut.hidden=NO;
    self.tableVW.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
    [self.tableVW setEditing: YES animated: YES];   
}
```

Cancel Button Code:

```
-(void) cancelTableEditClick: (UIButton *) sender
{
    self.cancelOut.hidden=YES;
    self.selectAllOut.hidden=YES;
    btn=FALSE;
    self.tableVW.allowsSelection = NO;
    self.toolBarOut.hidden=YES;
    [self.tableVW setEditing: NO animated: YES];   
    [self.tableVW reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use YES/NO as the value of `btn`, not TRUE/FALSE. In Objective-C, a `BOOL` variable only has two value:`YES`, `NO`.


Second, you can check if the code `[cellVal viewWithTag:10]` in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` return `nil`? Because you call `[self.tableVW reloadData]`, this will call the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` again, and your button will be set hidden, your code is correct, so check if you did not get the button by `viewWithTag:10`.

Answer (score 0):

i got simple answer,just do like this,inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath: delegate function,
set this custom button to the Accessoryview,

```
UIButton *myAccessoryButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[myAccessoryButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 48.0, 48.0)];
[myAccessoryButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myAccessoryButton addTarget:self action:@selector(detailBtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cellVal setAccessoryView:myAccessoryButton];
```

then the cal the detail function,

```
- (IBAction)detailBtn:(UIButton*)sender {
    NSLog(@"Detail btn clicked.... ");
}
```

now you can hide the button when you long pressed